# Jupyter Notebook Execution order of cells when using "run all"

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have a strange behavior of my current Jupyter Notebook (Python) installation (v5.7 Win10 Python (Anaconda)). When I reset my notebook and clear the output of all cells and re-run all cells the execution order is not top to bottom!

The first cells are executed normally in the right order, but then some cells are skipped and executed later. Of course this results in problems when variables are declared in a upper cell and reused later...

Has anyone the same problem or know some tricks to fix this issue?

Comment: are you at liberty to provide an example which we can check/test ourselves ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a brief look around the issue seems to be due ipykernel. If you downgrade to pykernel-4.9.0 this issue should disappear.

My source of this information is from a reported [github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4052). This has been going on for a week or so, looking at the comments and currently there is no other suggested solution

Edit/Update: The issue is being worked on right now [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/pull/362) and has been added to the 5.1 milestone so it should work again when 5.1 comes out

Comment: Downgrading the ipykernel: `conda install -c anaconda ipykernel=4.9.0`